# Kill program listening to a given port

Tags: python

Before the main code execution starts, I want to check if a particular port is open or not.. and if it is.. then close the port so that code can start "cleanly".

So I google online and found the code here:
http://www.paulwhippconsulting.com.au/tips/63-finding-and-killing-processes-on-ports

But just pasting the code from there:

```
import os
import subprocess
import re

ports = ['1234','5678','9101']


popen = subprocess.Popen(['netstat', '-lpn'],
                         shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(data, err) = popen.communicate()

pattern = "^tcp.*((?:{0})).* (?P[0-9]*)/.*$"
pattern = pattern.format(')|(?:'.join(ports))
prog = re.compile(pattern) #<---- error line
for line in data.split('\n'):
    match = re.match(prog, line)
    if match:
        pid = match.group('pid')
        subprocess.Popen(['kill', '-9', pid])
```

But it throws an error.

```
 raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unknown specifier: ?P[
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fellow who posted that snippet forgot to HTML-escape his code! The correct code is as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess
import re

ports = ['1234','5678','9101']


popen = subprocess.Popen(['netstat', '-lpn'],
                         shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(data, err) = popen.communicate()

pattern = "^tcp.*((?:{0})).* (?P<pid>[0-9]*)/.*$"
pattern = pattern.format(')|(?:'.join(ports))
prog = re.compile(pattern)
for line in data.split('\n'):
    match = re.match(prog, line)
    if match:
        pid = match.group('pid')
        subprocess.Popen(['kill', '-9', pid])
```

Note that `<pid>` follows the `?P`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>For those reading, `netstat` is a windows-only command.</strike> Also if you're doing this over and over, note that there are pip packages that can do this for you!

1. [killport](https://github.com/dannysepler/killport)
2. [freeport](https://github.com/yashbathia/freeport)

Comment: It's used in Linux, here's a guide on installing it.
https://linuxconfig.org/bash-netstat-command-not-found-debian-ubuntu-linux